# Request.Files by name in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am passing in a filename that I then want to request.files but it keeps returning null.  Here is the code:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("AddTechNote", "Ticket", FormMethod.Post))
 <div class="col-md-10">
       <input type="file" id="fileToUpload" name="fileToUpload" />
       <span class="field-validation-error" id="spanfile"></span>
 </div>
```

and in the controller:

```
public ActionResult AddTechNote(TicketView ticketReturn, string Note, bool PublicNote, string fileToUpload, string CopyIntoEmail)
{
        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileToUpload];
        string _fileName = null;

        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
               _fileName = new FileController().UploadFile(file, "Tickets", ticketReturn.TicketNumber.ToString());
        }
```

The view is not strongly typed (at least not to this model). The input field is inside a form.

Comment: you have to make `string fileToUpload` to `HttpPostedFileBase fileToUpload`, because fileToUpload is a `input type='file'`. And then use `fileToUpload` to get the file content. Use `fileToUpload.FileName` to get the file name.

Comment: Wow if that is it - I am an idiot, sorry.  Let me test

Comment: @ramiramilu I am getting an error now on Request.Files line that saying the overload method has invalid arguments.

Comment: @ramiramilu, No that's not correct. Request.Files takes string as key and not postedfilebase.

Comment: Okay good I needed to do .FileName then, is that correct?

Comment: @Rahul Yes, I already mentioned in my initial comment to use FileName, if we already get HttpPostedFileBase, then why again we have to go for `Request.Files[]`. All we need to do is to use that object and use `.FileName` to get the file name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having `string fileToUpload` you need to have `HttpPostedFileBase fileToUpload` and use `fileToUpload` in subsequent code as shown below.

```
public ActionResult AddTechNote(TicketView ticketReturn, string Note, bool PublicNote, HttpPostedFileBase fileToUpload, string CopyIntoEmail)
{
        string _fileName = null;

        if (fileToUpload != null && fileToUpload.ContentLength > 0)
        {
               _fileName = new FileController().UploadFile(fileToUpload, "Tickets", ticketReturn.TicketNumber.ToString());
        }
  ...........
}
```

Also make sure you have `multipart/form-data` set for your `BeginForm`, for example -

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Comment: I already did that but the file is still coming back null. I was about to change the original question to reflect this.

Comment: Have you used the same parameter name as of your input type='file' name? Also show us your `Html.BeginForm()` code. It should be `multipart` form like - `@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))`

Comment: Isn't that what I am showing in my view code above?

Comment: ramiramilu, I Just added that to my OP

Comment: Can you try by putting multipart form part in the code as well.